# Botman Studio with VK Community Callback driver hears not works inside Group

Tags: php, vk, botman

1. **hears** and **fallback** WORKS fine both:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\BotManController;
use BotMan\BotMan\Messages\Conversations\Conversation;
    
$botman = resolve('botman');
$botman->hears('Начать', function($bot) {
 $bot->startConversation(new OnboardingConversation);
}); //this works
$botman->fallback(function($bot) {
 $bot->startConversation(new OnboardingConversation);
}); //this works
```

3. inside group with VK driver **hears** NOT WORKS, but **fallback** WORKS:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\BotManController;
use BotMan\BotMan\Messages\Conversations\Conversation;
    
$botman = resolve('botman');
$botman->group(['driver' => [VkCommunityCallbackDriver::class]], function($botman) {    
 $botman->hears('Начать', function($bot) {
  $bot->startConversation(new OnboardingConversation);
 }); //this NOT works
 $botman->fallback(function($bot) {
  $bot->startConversation(new OnboardingConversation);
 }); //this works
});
```

all I want to do - universal bot for VK and Telegram for example, but I need to check if user in blacklist in target platform, so if "Driver" is some similar to "MatchingMiddleware" from botman - I don't understand why hears not works inside of "Group", this is official example from website:
[official botman video tutorial screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Me07p.png)

This example not works too: https://botman.io/2.0/receiving#command-groups-drivers

On VK Driver website there is no information about "Group": https://github.com/yageorgiy/botman-vk-community-callback-driver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE:**
I checked Marcel videos and his workflow, and a lot of times in Botman videos he used some magic keys in Sublime Text editor, so I google it, and it was PHP Companion, so I installed Sublime Text and PHP Companion through Tools->Command Pallete, and clicked on VkCommunityCallbackDriver, and then again Tools->Command Pallete with command PHP Companion:Find Use, and this code appear:

```
use BotMan\Drivers\VK\VkCommunityCallbackDriver;
use BotMan\Drivers\Telegram\TelegramDriver;
```

the magic worked and now the group method with the driver works, I still don't understand why this is not indicated anywhere in the documentation or in video courses, as if the group method is not the main one.

I am still don't understand why it's not works from "the box", because I always thought that coders using this complex solutions for easy life. But after 2 days of empty searching I am tired, so I wrote custom Middleware to "hears" VK Driver only, based on official video tutorials from Botman https://beyondco.de/course/build-a-chatbot/middleware-system/matching-middleware:

**App\Middleware\VkMatchingMiddleware.php**

```
<?php
namespace App\Middleware;
use BotMan\BotMan\BotMan;
use BotMan\BotMan\Interfaces\Middleware\Matching;
use BotMan\BotMan\Messages\Incoming\IncomingMessage;

class VkMatchingMiddleware implements Matching
{
    /**
* Handle a captured message.
*
* @param IncomingMessage $message
* @param callable $next
* @param BotMan $bot
*
* @return mixed
*/
    public function matching(IncomingMessage $message, $pattern, $regexMatched)
    {
        return $regexMatched && isset($message->getExtras()["client_info"]);
    }
}
```

**Routes\botman.php**:

```
<?php
use App\Http\Controllers\BotManController;
use BotMan\BotMan\Messages\Conversations\Conversation;
use App\Middleware\VkMatchingMiddleware;

$VkMatchingMiddleware = new VkMatchingMiddleware();

$botman = resolve('botman');

$botman->hears('Begin', function($bot) {
    $extras = $bot->getMessage()->getExtras();
    $bot->reply(print_r($extras, 1));
})->middleware($VkMatchingMiddleware);

$botman->fallback(function($bot) {    
    $bot->reply('fallback');
});
```

If someone knows why it works this way but not works from Vanilla, I will glad to see explanation.